# Windows 10 doesn't boot anymore after installing ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, 18.04, windows-10

after installing Ubuntu 18.04 on my PC I can't seem to boot into windows anymore (It shows up in GRUB though). When i select it, it just shows the windows logo and after a few seconds it reboots again.

Does anybody know a fix?

Comment: If you select the EFI menu (some function key like f12 at power-up) to select device or OS to boot, and select windows, does it boot? That would remove grub from the boot sequence.

Comment: Hey, so i tried that multiple times vut it still just goes to grub. Also, i tried reseting windows but that didn't work either....